# Wrap hyperlink in td with same hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, html-table

Not sure how to word the title.

Basically I have a table with links in the 3rd column.
These are just text, not actual hyperlinks.

Is there a way with jQuery to save the text as a variable and then wrap that text with itself?
Does that make sense?

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    var sitename = $("td.column-3",this)
    $('table tr td:nth-child(3) ').contents().wrap('<a href="/hello/" />');
})
```

I would like to wrap with

```
.wrap('<a href="/'+sitename+/" />');
```

instead.

Anyone help??

Comment: `.html()` on a link will give you the text you want to keep.

Comment: `sitename` is a jQuery object - if you append that to a string you will see `[object Object]`. What value are you trying to append from that selector?

Comment: take a look http://jsfiddle.net/pnhPG/. this is binding a `<a>` element to the whole `<td>`. is this what you need?

Comment: cr0ss that is pretty much perfect. If you have a look at http://icebergmags.co.uk/ you will see there is a tiny problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pnhPG/1/)**

This is wrapping an `<a>` element to the whole `<td>`, setting it's `href` to the text inside the `td`.

```
$(function () {

    $("tr").each(function () {
        var sitename = $("td.column-3", this);
        sitename.wrap('<a href=' + sitename.text() + ' />');
    })

});
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a if null? because if you look at http://icebergmags.co.uk/ the fields with nothing in I think is breaking it? Thanks so far cr0ss!!